# Using tfs 2015 and tfs 2018 agents in the same machine

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I was working with Team Foundation Server 2015 where I had some releases configured for some environments (env1, env2, ...).

I installed TFS 2018 in a different machine. I migrated the code and I have completed the creation of a build definition.

I'd like to configure a release, using the old TFS 2015 environments. Can I install a TFS 2018 Agent, in the environments where I had installed the TFS 2015 agents?

In this way both of the agents would work without issues? The TFS 2015 Agent would work with TFS 2015 and the TFS 2018 Agent would work with TFS 2018 (both in the same machine).

I want to do this because my team is still working with TFS 2015, but as I am still setting up and testing TFS 2018 build/releases, I'd like TFS 2015 to work flawless (whithout any issue) while I am setting up and using TFS 2018 (with TFS 2018 Agents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different versions of agents can easily work on the same machine. As long as you keep the rule of thumb of 1 cpu core for the system and 1 cpu core per agent.
I have had multiple versions of agents running before on the same build machine without any issue. The only problem would be to try and connect an agent with 1.* versions to TFS 2018, since that wouldn't work, but since that is not what you are asking for, I would say that you are good to go :-)

Comment: I just want the agents of TFS 2015 to keep working with TFS 2015 and, at the same time, the agents I'll install for TFS 2018 should work with TFS 2018 (so in each machine I will have a TFS 2015 agent and a TFS 2018 agent working).

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem with that. The agents do not have anything shared, except system resources. So if you have a machine with 2 agents on it, one for a TFS 2015 instance and one for a TFS 2018 instance, you shouldn't encounter any problems.

Comment: One core per agent is not a good heuristic in my experience. Builds are typically **I/O limited**, not CPU limited. Disk speed and memory speed will become a problem long before CPU becomes an issue unless you only have a slow, single-core CPU.

Comment: @Daniel Mann Well that is true, as mentioned it is mostly regarding it as a rule of thumb. As you mention, there are a lot of different other aspects there should be considered. So thumbs up for mentioning it :)

Comment: Hello, when you say "one core per agent..." I don't understand what you mean by that. You mean to set the agent according to the cores or you mean I should install only 2 agents If I only have 2 cores? Please explain this. Thanks

Comment: Let's say that you have 4 cores, then theoretically, you should be able to handle 3 agents and the system. Like @Daniel Mann mentioned, there are some other I/O limits that can influence builds.